# Building Visual Studio Extension Editor - all of a sudden (VS 16.8+) "bufferAdapter is not a VsTextDocData" on save

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

As said in the title - I have this Visual Studio Extension that has been working fine for many years and it has supported Visual Studio from VS2010 to VS2019.

But just after the last VS update (16.8.6) I got "bufferAdapter is not a VsTextDocData" when trying to save.

This however only happens in .netStandard or .netCore projects.

The Extension is huge so if you have any pointers... TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! - It was the change of the "Find experience" that was the root cause (even though save was the indicator)

I stopped to implement these interfaces to make things work again:

```
IVsFindTarget      
IVsTextImage       
IVsTextSpanSet     
IVsTextBuffer      
IVsTextView       
IVsCodeWindow
```

Comment: Thanks @HansKarlsen. This was the only solution I found for this problem. In our circumstance, we had to stop implementing IVsTextLines and IVsTextStream.